# Left justify equation in proof but keep = alignment

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, align

```
\begin{proof}
Let $g_1, g_2 \in G$. Then $\theta(g_1) = Ng_1$ and $\theta(g_2) = Ng_2$. \\
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\text{ Now, } \theta(g_1g_2) &= Ng_1g_2 \\
& = Ng_1 Ng_2 \\
& = \theta(g_1) \theta(g_2)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$\therefore \theta$ is a group homomorphism. $\theta$ is clearly onto.
\end{proof}
```

Is there a way to **left** justify the *first* line of the equation, but then keep the = signs aligned in the subsequent lines? I've tried many combinations of \begin{align} etc with no luck. (It appears that the \begin{equation} favors center alignment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `aligned`. I also provide what I firmly believe is a better version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Let $g_1, g_2 \in G$. Then $\theta(g_1) = Ng_1$ and $\theta(g_2) = Ng_2$. \\
$\begin{aligned}
\text{Now, } \theta(g_1g_2) &= Ng_1g_2 \\
& = Ng_1 Ng_2 \\
& = \theta(g_1) \theta(g_2)\\
\end{aligned}$\\
$\therefore \theta$ is a group homomorphism. $\theta$ is clearly onto.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Let $g_1, g_2 \in G$. Then $\theta(g_1) = Ng_1$ and $\theta(g_2) = Ng_2$. Now
\begin{align*}
\theta(g_1g_2) &= Ng_1g_2 \\
& = Ng_1 Ng_2 \\
& = \theta(g_1) \theta(g_2)
\end{align*}
Therefore $\theta$ is a group homomorphism. $\theta$ is clearly onto.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second sample is missing a line break before the "Now"?

Comment: I must agree, I like this better than the _\noindent_ clause of @Zarko's solution

Comment: @AthenaWidget: In my eyes, the second sample looks far better!

Comment: @AthenaWidget Why should there be a line break?

Comment: @egreg. I wanted the "Now" to start on a new line and be left justified. But I'm considering AdoAmmar's comment. I'll take them both as is. thx!

Comment: @AthenaWidget., I didn't bother with theorem environment, so I instead it use `noindent` to show, that equation is not left aligned. If you have provide MWE instead of code snippet, my answer would consider this environment too.  I just add it now, for completeness of my answer.

Comment: @AthenaWidget There's no reason for starting a new line. I understand it's a stylistic issue, but it's just writing in plain English. Also the `\therefore` symbol should be avoided in such contexts: writing the full adverb is better for understanding.

Comment: @egreg. Agreed about the therefore symbol. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Let $g_1, g_2 \in G$. Then $\theta(g_1) = Ng_1$ and $\theta(g_2) = Ng_2$. 
    \begin{flalign*}
\text{Now, } \theta(g_1g_2) 
    & = Ng_1g_2                 &&  \\
    & = Ng_1 Ng_2               &&  \\
   & = \theta(g_1) \theta(g_2)
    \end{flalign*}
$\therefore\theta$ is a group homomorphism. $\theta$ is clearly onto.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beat me by 4 min.

Comment: Perfect. I had this fixation that I _had_ to use {equation}. Thx!

Comment: @AthenaWidget, I add proof environment. Is now better?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution consists in nesting `align*` in the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Let $g_1, g_2 \in G$. Then $\theta(g_1) = Ng_1$ and $\theta(g_2) = Ng_2$. \\
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
\text{Now, } \theta(g_1g_2) &= Ng_1g_2 \\
& = Ng_1 Ng_2 \\
& = \theta(g_1) \theta(g_2)
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
$\therefore \theta$ is a group homomorphism. $\theta$ is clearly onto.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is an interesting extension for another feature: it defines commands for `medium-sized` formulae (it happens from time to time that one would like to have  a size between \textstyle and \displaystyle).